# How to increment an ID in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to increment an ID I am assigning to a view in Backbone. With the code below, each element gets an ID of 1 and I've tried a dozen ways to increment the id using id++ in different locations so I can interact with the elements based on their id. I am using the following code to set the ID. Any help in finding a way to increment the ID by 1 would be extremely appreciated.

```
 initialize:function(models, options){
        this.model.set("view",this);
        this.model.set("rank", 1, 'rank++');
        this.model.set("id", 1);
    },
```

Comment: Have you looked into client ids (cid) ?

Comment: you are assigning an `id` to model, not to view. Secondly, models already have an `id` by default, that's called `cid`, of course it's not the same as `id` but should serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very familiar with Backbone.js, but you could always use a global variable.

```
var nextID = 1;
...
...
initialize: function(models, options){
        this.model.set("id", nextID++);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to increase the 'id' each time you create a view and and avoid creating any global variables then you can use javascript closures to do it.

```
function counter(){
    var count=0;
    return function (){ return ++count;};
}
var increase = counter()

var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(model,options){
        var id = increase();
        this.model.set('id',id);
    }
});
```

now whenever you will create an instance of this view its id will be increased by 1.
you can read more on closures here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures .